# In need of help/hints to find A if $(2A)^{-1}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0\\ 2 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to find the way to solve this problem.

Now based on what I've read so far that if $(k A)^{-1} = 1/k A^{-1}$

Since we already have the inverse of $(2A)^{-1}$ do I need to create an ***I***?

Comment: HINT: $((2A)^{-1})^{-1} = 2A$.

Comment: Yes thank you, I'm a bit of a slow learner, might take some time wrap around this. But the first comment and yours has helped me understanding. Also does this mean if I need to find $A$ I only need to divide the $2A$ with 2?